# Conflicting definition of eulerian graph and finite graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading Van Lint and Wilson: *A Course in Combinatorics*.

There is one part of the book where he defines a finite graph:

> A graph is ﬁnite when both E(G) and V (G) are ﬁnite sets.
>
> **Theorem 1.1.** A ﬁnite graph G has an even number of vertices with odd valency.

Reading it further, there is:

> **Theorem 1.2.** A ﬁnite graph G with no isolated vertices (but possibly with multiple edges) is Eulerian if and only if it is connected and every vertex has even degree.

It was first said that a finite graph has an odd valency at each vertex, now a finite graph with every vertex with even degree is presented. How should I proceed? Should I drop the condition given in the first theorem (odd valency)? Does Eulerian graph mean a finite graph without this condition? I believe it is, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion is that you read the theorem the following way:

> A ﬁnite graph G has an even number of vertices, each with odd valency.

What the theorem states actually is:

> A ﬁnite graph G has an [even number of vertices with odd valency].

Or, to make it more clear:

**Theorem** In a finite graph, the number of vertices which has an odd valency is even.

Comment: Now I get it. It could - for example - have 15 vertices but only two of them having odd valency. Now I understand.

Comment: @VladimirPutin Yes. The Theorem is probably not stated the best way, it could be read both ways.

Comment: Take [this example](http://i.imgur.com/5hONhYm.png), is it a finite graph? It has an even number of vertices with odd valency, but it also has an odd number of vertices with odd valency.

Comment: @VladimirPutin Finite means that the number of vertices and edges are finite. So yes. An example of a graph which is not finite is the following: Vertices are the whole numbers, and edges are the pairs of consecutive numbers.

Comment: @VladimirPutin In general, if you can draw all vertices and all edges it means it is finite.....

Answer (score 3):

Where does it say that a finite graph has an odd valency at each vertex? I see it saying the number of such vertices is *even*. Note that zero is an even number. There is no contradiction here.

Comment: Even number of vertices with odd valency. Doesn't it mean that each vertex has odd valency?

Comment: No, it means that the number of vertices with odd valency is one of 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, … (The result comes from the fact that each edge has two ends, so the total number of ends of edges is even.)

Comment: @VladimirPutin If a graph has $3$ vertices, can that Theorem say that ALL vertices have odd valency?

Comment: @N.S. But if it has 3 vertices, can it still be called a finite graph?

Comment: @VladimirPutin Well three vertices and 2 edges are a finite graph....